How can I use assumption in order to find imaginary part?
The code is below.
expr = Vx/Rp + Vx/(s Lp) == (VLO - Vx) s CGD;
sol = Solve[expr, Vx]
Av = Vx/VLO /. sol[[1, 1]]
Ag = Av /. s -> I w
$Assumptions = {Vx, VLO, Rp, w, CGD} \[Element] Reals;
Im[Ag]

It seemed that it just ignores my assumption.

Try ComplexExpand[Ag].

@A.Kato But I have to find Im part manually with ComplexExpand

Ag // Im // ComplexExpand

Using ReIm:
Last@ComplexExpand[ReIm[Ag]]


Or using ReplaceAll:
ComplexExpand[Ag] /. a_ + b_*I :> b


To simplify further, use ExpandAll and Simplify:
Last@Map[Simplify]@ExpandAll[ComplexExpand[ReIm[Ag]]]


Additional Explanation:
In MMA, it is often unnecessary to use Assumptions when dealing with expressions involving complex numbers whose real and imaginary parts depend on symbolic variables. This is because MMA implicitly assumes that all symbols represent real numbers unless otherwise specified. For instance, if you evaluate the real part of an expression like a + b I, MMA assumes that both a and b are real and returns a without requiring explicit assumptions.  I think this was already pointed out to you by @Bob Halon in a comment.
However, the situation changes when the expressions involve radicals (e.g., square roots). In such cases, assumptions become essential because the radical introduces ambiguities regarding the nature of the values involved. For example, the square root of a negative number is complex, and MMA cannot make automatic assumptions about the signs or ranges of the symbols. Thus, explicit assumptions are required to correctly compute the real and imaginary parts.
Example without Radicals:
ComplexExpand[Re[a + b I]]

(*a*)

Here, MMA assumes a and b are real, so it simplifies the expression to a without needing any assumptions.
Example with Radicals:
ComplexExpand[Re[Sqrt[a - b] + c  I]]

(*((a - b)^2)^(1/4) Cos[1/2 Arg[a - b]]*)

The above result reflects the fact that the square root introduces a dependency on the argument (Arg) of the expression a - b, and thus, MMA cannot make automatic assumptions about whether a - b is positive, negative, or even complex.
By providing assumptions, we can refine this result further. For example:
Assuming[a > b, Refine[ComplexExpand[Re[Sqrt[a - b] + c I]]]]

With these assumption, MMA simplifies the real part to Sqrt[a - b], as the expression under the square root is positive.
Now, if we change the assumption to a < b:
Assuming[a < b, Refine[ComplexExpand[Re[Sqrt[a - b] + c*I]]]]

(*0*)

In this case, MMA returns 0 for the real part because a - b is negative, and thus the square root yields a purely imaginary number.

Is there a way to use assumption in Mathematica?

@kile See the update, please!

Module[{cpx = ComplexExpand[Ag]}, 
 Simplify[(cpx - (cpx /. I -> -I))/(2 I)]]



What does this mean?
(cpx - (cpx /. I -> -I))/(2 I)

Taking the imaginary part of cpx: if $z = x+ i y$, then $\bar{z}=x - i y$, so $Im(z)=y=(z-\bar{z})/(2i)$.

Why not simply ComplexExpand[Im[Ag]] or FullSimplify[(Ag - Conjugate[Ag])/(2*I),  Element[Vx | VLO | Rp | w | CGD | Lp, Reals]] ?

@yarchik I didn't think of that. Why not simply post your answer?

I find that the substitution I->-I sometimes fails, which is why I avoid it.

@A.Kato Is this possible to use assumption instead?

As Mathematica Documentation says, ComplexExpand assumes all variables are real --- that is exactly what you assumed. Therefore, there is no merit using Assumptions.
